# Why QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable has no effect?

Tags: qt

I just want to add movable label to the scene:

```
QGraphicsWidget* w = scene->addWidget( new QLabel( "Test Label" ) );
w->setFlag( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true );
```

but label stays unmovable.

Comment: Thats how `QGraphicsProxyWidget` works. It posts the mouse events to the widget. You can subclass it and change this behavior, or you can just simply use [`QGraphicsTextItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html).

Comment: @thuga Please suggest me what need to reimplement to propagate mouse event properly. I can't find appropriate example.

Comment: Well mouse event handling obviously. See [this forum post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28434-Move-QGraphicsProxyWidget). There are more of these around if you google *QGraphicsProxyWidget itemismovable*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the item is not set as selectable, it will also not be able to be moved.

```
w->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
```

In addition, as you're adding a widget to the scene, the widget is embedded in a [QGraphicsProxyWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsproxywidget.html). As the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsproxywidget.html#details) states:  -

> *It forwards events between the two objects and translates between QWidget's integer-based geometry and QGraphicsWidget's qreal-based geometry.*

So the mouse events that would normally be handled by the QGraphicsItem are being propagated to the widget and this doesn't know that it is in a proxy widget. In order to drag the widget around the scene, you'd need to change this so that the QGraphicsProxyWidget handles the events.

One method would be to derive from QGraphicsProxyWidget and override the [mouseMoveEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsproxywidget.html#mouseMoveEvent), mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent. Then detect whether the mouse is clicked and released, without dragging, in which case propagate the event to the widget, else if you detect that the mouse has moved in the move event, without a call to mouseReleaseEvent, then move the proxy widget accordingly and set the event as accepted with [QEvent::accept()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qevent.html#accept)

Comment: First: it doesn't work for Label. Second: it is wrong, that "If the item is not set as selectable, it will also not be able to be moved." - Try to add rectangle scene->addRect(), and set ItemIsSelectable flag. The widget will be movable, without flag for selection.

Comment: "and set ItemIsSelectable flag...without flag for selection" - If you set the selectable flag, then the item is not "without the flag for selection"

Comment: sorry - not ItemIsSelectable, only ItemIsMovable for rectangle.

Comment: No problem. However, if you can't select an item, you shouldn't be able to move it.